# Using Slim PHP framework to achieve clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-5.3, slim

I am trying to clean my url, and since I am already using the slim framework for php, I thought i might use that has a tool to achieve clean url rather than .htaccess.

For example, I have the following code:

```
$app->get('/onemonth', function() use($app){
  $app->render('searchPage.php?in_one_month');
})->name('onemonth');
```

It will only work if i remove the uri of searchPage.php. In other words, if i just have it as such:

```
  $app->render('searchPage.php');
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you are trying to do.
I *guess* you want to pass some argument to your `searchPage.php` file?

If that's the case you can do the following:

```
$app->render('searchPage.php', array('in_one_month' => true));
```

Then, in your `searchPage.php` file you should have access to `$data['in_one_month']` (I haven't tested the last bit)

**Edit:**

I set up a small repository for demonstration:
[GitHub](https://github.com/mgansler/so31821402)

Comment: in the page i entered     <?php echo "$data['in_one_month']" ; ?>
and nothing seems to have echo out

Comment: It's `$data` because that the name of the variable the parameter is passed to, see https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/2.x/Slim/View.php#L268

Oh I see - because of the extract you can use $in_one_month right away. I should have read the documentation before answering :)
I jave updated the repo